# Is Merge Request Squash Commit Option Safe

Tags: git, gitlab

My development team recently moved to using Gitlab.  I had suggested that on merge requests we need to squash commits.  I got a lot of push back that it would not be safe.

A typical feature development cycle includes daily commits and pushes on a feature branch.  It also includes once daily git pulls from master to stay in sync with other changes.  Sometimes this involves resolving merge conflicts.

They believe all of this merging from master and then performing a merge request to master and squashing commits could result in possible undetected merge problems.

Is there any truth to this?  My assumption is that squashing commits should be safe no matter what.

Comment: The unsafe part of this is the "daily commits and pushes" ritual.  Commit when it helps to understand or explain or remember the code, rebase for clarity before publication, push and merge the reviewed and clarified result.  If there's someone there insisting on seeing "daily commits", make special commits for them so they don't feel left out of the real work. Squash merging is a distasteful lobotomy, if the history you're pushing is so worthless nobody ever wants to see it on the mainline, what was the point of pushing it in the first place?

Answer (score 13):

At the risk of repeating (some or even all of) what is in [bk2204's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58465940/1256452), I'll take a stab at this.

(Note that there's a problem with any answer, because you used the word *safe*.  That's not a term with a clear and obvious technical definition.  Something totally safe in one situation might be less-so in another.  Analogies always fall apart when pushed too hard, but consider, e.g., walking down the street without wearing, hand, knee, and elbow protection, vs zooming down the street on rollerblades—or should I say ["inline skates"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollerblade)?—without said protection.)

I always like to say that Git is not about *files* but rather about *commits* (which then hold files).  That holds in this case as well:

- Each commit has a snapshot of (all of your) files, plus some metadata.
- Merging simply combines snapshots—typically 3 of them—according to a defined set of rules.
- Regular merge and squash-merge use the same mechanism to achieve the final set of *files* that are to go into the next commit.
- But, the *commits* made by `git merge --squash` (or its equivalent clicky button on some web interface) are different from the commits made by `git merge` (or its equivalent clicky button).

In this case, the entire difference lies in the *parent linkage* of the final commit.  On its face, this might seem like a tiny little difference ... but the way commits link up, in Git, *is* history, in Git.  There's no such thing as *file* history: there only on *commit* history.  So this small difference is actually huge—especially when you consider how squash-merges should, in general, affect peoples' future behaviors.

To see how this works in practice, it's necessary to understand the *commit graph*.  This gets us into the metadata I mentioned in the first bullet point above.

#### Visualizing the commit graph

I find it helpful, sometimes, to look at the actual, concrete content of a real commit.  Here's a commit in the Git repository for Git itself:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468
$ git cat-file -p 08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468 | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 27fee9c50528ef1b0960c2c342ff139e36ce2076
parent 07f25ad8b235c2682a36ee76d59734ec3f08c413
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1570770961 +0900
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1570771489 +0900

Eighth batch

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

(I replaced the `@` with space just to maybe, possibly, cut down on the amount of spam that goes to pobox.com.  Note that you can actually just `git cat-file -p HEAD`, too: I use the raw hash ID here to help cement the idea that it's the hash ID that matters.)

This is actually the full and complete text of the commit.  The hash ID, `08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468`, is a cryptographic checksum of this stuff.<sup>1</sup>  Git stores the snapshot itself indirectly, as a *tree* object,<sup>2</sup> which has its own hash ID.  The remainder of the text is the rest of the metadata: author and committer (name, email address, and date-and-time stamp); parent commits, listed by hash ID; and the log message.

So, each commit has its own unique hash ID.  That hash ID refers to *that* commit; no other commit can *ever* have the same hash ID.<sup>3</sup>  Moreover, each commit refers, by hash ID, to its immediate *parent* commit(s).  These parent hash IDs are required to be the IDs of some commits that existed before *this* commit was made.  For ordinary (non-merge) commits, the (single) parent is whichever commit you had checked out at the time you made the commit.

When we look at a new Git repository with just three commits in it, we can draw this out by using single uppercase letters to stand in for the actual hash IDs:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Here, commit `A` is the first commit we ever made.  It has *no* parent, because the parent is the commit that existed before commit `A`, and there isn't one.  This special case is what Git calls a *root commit*.<sup>4</sup>  But then once we had commit `A`, we made commit `B`, so `B`'s parent is `A`.  Similarly, we were using commit `B` when we made commit `C`, so `C`'s parent is `B`.

When something holds the hash ID of a commit, we say that that thing *points to* the commit.  So commit `C` points to `B`, which points to `A`, which is a root commit and nothing points there.

In these drawings it's easy to see where the chain ends, but in a real Git repository, with real—and random-looking—hash IDs, it's hard.  We need a quick and easy way to *find* commit `C`, at this point.  So, partly as a sop to us mere humans who can't remember raw hash IDs, Git provides us with *branch names*.

A branch name simply holds the hash ID of one commit.  In our case, we'll use the name `master` to hold the actual hash ID of the commit we're calling `C`.  We can draw that like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

The name `master` points to the *last* commit in the chain, i.e., `C`.  I've stopped drawing the internal arrows because they get harder to draw soon.  Just remember that they always point backwards.  They're a consequence of the `parent` lines in the actual commits, so they can never change—unlike the *branch name* arrows, which *do* change.

Let's add a new commit `D` to our chain, by doing `git checkout master` and then updating files, `git add`-ing, and `git commit`-ing.  New commit `D` will point back to existing commit `C` as `D`'s parent:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D
```

Then, since `D` *is* the new *last* commit for the chain, Git will update our current branch name, `master`, to point to `D` instead of `C`.  We can also move `D` up a line in the drawing.  The result is:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

To add a branch, we just create a new name, pointing to the current commit.  Let's make new branch `dev` and have it point to `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- dev, master
```

Now we need one additional bit of notation: we have to remember which *branch name* we have checked out.  We have commit `D` out, but when we add new commit `E`, only *one* of the two branch names should move.  For this purpose, we'll add `(HEAD)` after one of the branch names.  That's the *name* we have out; `git commit` will move that name.  So if we `git checkout dev`, we stay with commit `D`—and all of its files—and then when we make the new commit we get:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- dev
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, it's the SHA-1 checksum of the word `commit` followed by a space followed by the size in bytes, expressed in decimal, which is `280`, followed by an ASCII NUL character, followed by the bytes of the content:

```
$ (printf 'commit 280\0'; git cat-file -p HEAD) | shasum
08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468  -
```

This technique works for all four of Git's object types: print the name of the type, a space, the size of the object in bytes as decimalized ASCII, an ASCII NUL, and then the content.  For commits, the content is the text of the commit, which is in the order: `tree` and hash, each parent in order, `author` line, `committer` line, any additional header lines, blank line, subject-and-body.  For annotated tags, look at any annotated tags.  Blob objects have the obvious text.  The tricky one is tree objects, which are binary and have several semi-arbitrary rules applied to enforce ordering.  Tree objects are going to be the big stumbling block in converting to SHA-256.

<sup>2</sup>This allows tree objects to be shared: if two different commits save the same snapshot, they don't need to re-save the tree.  This sharing applies recursively to sub-trees and, of course, to individual blob objects as well.  After all, once an object is written, no part of it can be changed—the hash ID checksum would change and the result would be a different object—so if you have the same content, it reduces to the same hash ID.  The object database, which is a simple key-value store, detects that the key is already present and therefore does not bother to store the data again.

<sup>3</sup>Note that if you make the same commit, with the same tree, same author, same log message, and—crucially—same *time stamps and parents*, you get the same commit.  If *any* of those are different, including a parent hash or a time stamp, you get a new and different commit.  So, if you re-commit the *same* snapshot, you do it at a different time and with a different parent commit: the new commit is therefore not the same as the old one.  Hence the new commit gets a new hash.  Even if you use `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` to force the new commit to share the old commit's time-stamp, the *parent* hash will be different: the new commit refers back to some other existing commit, different from the original commit's parent(s), so again, re-committing the same snapshot gives you a new and different commit.

The only way to get Git to re-use the commit hash is to commit the same snapshot, at the same time, *with the same parents*.  In this case, it's OK to re-use the original commit, because the new commit *is* the original commit.  They are truly identical.  Nobody can tell them apart, so they might as well be the same commit.

<sup>4</sup>You can generate commit graphs that have more than one root commit, but many repositories have just the one original root.  It takes one of several slightly odd tricks to acquire an additional root commit.

---

#### Merge commits and the commit graph

A *merge commit*, in Git, is any commit with at least two parents (and usually only two parents).  We can't make a merge commit until we have a fork in the graph.  For instance, suppose the graph is linear up to commit `H`, after which it diverges like this:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- dev
```

We've already done a `git checkout master`, which means we have commit `J` checked out right now.  The name `dev` identifies commit `L`.

We now run `git merge dev`.  Git uses the *graph* to find the point at which the two branches were last brought together, which in this case is obviously commit `H`.  Git calls this the *merge base* commit.  The other two interesting commits are our current commit, `J`, and the one that the name `dev` points to, `L`.

Git will now, in effect:

- diff the contents of the merge base `H` commit vs our current commit `J`: this is *what we changed* since the base;
- diff `H` vs the other commit `L`: this is what *they* changed since the base;
- do its best to *combine* these two sets of changes.

The combined changes get applied to the contents from commit `H`.  That way, we get our changes *plus* their changes.  The precise details of the combining process can get pretty tricky, especially in the face of conflicts, but here, we're more interested in the result.  We'll assume there were no conflicts.

Since we ran `git merge` (not `git merge --squash`), Git will now commit the result.  The new commit advances our current branch, just like any other commit, but this time the new commit points back to *both* of the two branch-tip commits.  Hence we can draw the result like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- dev
```

Commit `M` has *two* parents, `J` and `L`.

Of course, we can add more every-day commits if we like:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- dev
```

New commit `N` has `M` as its parent, as usual.  When we have Git show us the commits that are *reachable from* `master`, Git will start with `N`, then move back one step to `M` and show us commit `M`.  Now Git has a choice: should it move back one step to `J`, or one step to `L`?

In general, Git actually does *both* of these.<sup>5</sup>  Neither parent is any "better" or "more important" than the other, so Git will follow both tracks—both legs of the merge—and visit commits `J` and `I`, but also `L` and `K`.  These tracks re-combine at `H`, so once Git reaches `H` it can move on to `G` and `F` and so on as before.

Note that merge commit `M` has its own snapshot, just like any other commit.  The *only* thing that is special about `M` here is that it has two parents.  The history, starting from `M` and working backwards, goes down both legs, then rejoins.

One reason this is so important is that a *future* merge's merge base depends on the *current* merge.  Let's draw a slightly different variant in which `dev` gets merged into `master` more than once.  We'll start with just one merge `M` in `master`, like this:

```
...--H---L--M--P   <-- master
      \    /
       I--J--N--O   <-- dev
```

(Yes, there's no `K`, I left it out to make the merge get the letter `M`. :-) )

Now we will `git checkout master` and `git merge dev` to make a new merge `q`.  Git will have to find the merge base between commit `P` and commit `O`.  To do that, it works backwards from `P`, going to `M` and then to both `L` and `J`.  It also works backwards from `O`, going to `N` and then `J`.

Commit `J` is *reachable from* both branches, and is the correct merge base.  It *is* the merge base *because* `M` links back to both `L` *and* `J`.  So that backwards link going from `M` to `J` is important here.  If we didn't have it, Git would have to keep going further, from `L` to `H`, and from `J` to `I` to `H`.

In other words, without the link afforded by merge commit `M`, the *next* merge would have to look at a diff from `H` to `P` (our changes) and from `H` to `O` (their changes) that *includes changes already merged*.  *With* the link, Git looks at a diff from `J` to `P`—which in effect is what we did in `L` and `P`—and from `J` to `O`, which in effect is what they did in `N` and `O`.  So the subsequent merge is *easier* (not trivial, of course, but easier).

---

<sup>5</sup>With `git log` and some other Git commands, you can use `--first-parent` to tell it to *ignore* the second parent, and any additional parents if they exist, for the purpose of that one command.  Note that the first parent of a merge is chosen at the time the merge is made.  It cannot be changed later.  It's always the commit you were on when you, or whoever, made the merge.  It's up to the *viewer* to decide whether this first parent is somehow "more important" than any other parent, but the only built-in flag here is `--first-parent`: there's no `--second-parent`, so either all parents are equal, or first-parent is more important.

---

#### A squash merge is not a merge

Suppose that instead of making merge `M` with `git merge dev`, we made it with `git merge --squash dev`.  Git would still:

- find merge base `H`;
- diff `H` vs `L` to see what we changed;
- diff `H` vs `J` to see what they changed; and
- combine the two diffs, applying the combination to the snapshot from `H`.

The command-line `git merge --squash` flag also sets the `--no-commit` flag, so that Git forces us to run `git commit` to make new commit `M`.  Most of the clicky buttons on web interfaces go ahead and make the commit themselves, and there's no good reason any more for command-line Git to stop like this, except that backwards compatibility requires it.  In any case, when we make the merge—or some clicky button does it—we get:

```
...--H---L--M   <-- master
      \
       I--J   <-- dev
```

Everything *else* is exactly the same, but commit `M` has no back-link to `dev`.

If we now go on as before and have:

```
...--H---L--M--P   <-- master
      \
       I--J--N--O   <-- dev
```

the *next* merge we run, with or without `--squash`, to bring `dev` into `master`, will compare commit `H` to commits `P` and `O`.  If we had to do something clever about merge conflicts when we made `M`, we'll probably have to do it again.

What this means in practice is that after `git merge --squash`, you should almost always *delete* the branch your just merged.  That is, having merged commit `J`, you should *delete* the name `dev`:

```
...--H---L--M   <-- master
      \
       I--J   [abandoned]
```

Commits `I` and `J` remain in your own repository for a while—exactly how long is kind of complicated—but with no *name* to find them, you'd have to remember their hash IDs, or at least the hash ID of commit `J`.

#### Complications

There's a further complication here if anyone has made some *other* name point to either commits `I` or `J` or any commit from which we can *find* `J` or `I`.  For instance, if we have:

```
...--H---L--M   <-- master
      \
       I--J   <-- dev
        \
         K   <-- d2
```

and then we delete the name `dev`, so that commit `J` becomes impossible to find unless you remember its hash ID, we end up with what *looks like* this:

```
...--H---L--M   <-- master
      \
       I--K   <-- d2
```

which now looks like commit `I` itself is something important we did while working on `d2`, rather than a side effect of starting work on `d2` after starting work on `dev` and making commit `I`.

This is a general rule about Git, not something specific to squash merges: it's the *commits* that matter, not so much the *branch names*.  A branch name is just a starting—or ending—point we use to *find* commits.  So when you move or delete branch names, if the *commits* can still be found from some other branch name, they're still in there.  Even if they *can't* be found, they're probably still in your repository somewhere.  Your Git will toss them out eventually, later, after deciding that they're unwanted rubbish.

We *find* commits by starting at branch names and working backwards.  When we find some commit this way, we say that it's *on the branch*, but it may be more accurate to say that it is *contained within the branch*.  Any one commit may be contained in many branches.  The set of branches that contain a commit changes when we add, delete, or move the branch names.

So the rule we must remember is this: **The commit *graph* never changes except by *adding* commits or *not being able to find* commits.  The branch names change all the time—most of the time, in such a way that we find new commits *and* keep finding the old ones too.**

#### With all this in mind, let's look at your particular situation

I'm going to skip over most of the complications that come up as we add multiple Git repositories.  A `git push` just sends commits to some other Git repository, asking them to set one of *their* branch names to point to the last of these new commits.  A `git pull` starts by running `git fetch`, which gets any new commits from some other Git repository and then updates your own Git's *remote-tracking* names—`origin/master` and the like—to remember the *last* commit in *their* corresponding branch.  The `git merge` you might do after a `git fetch` sometimes does a real merge, as described above, to make a new merge commit.  Sometimes it does a *fast-forward* operation, which amounts to checking out *their* tip commit and dragging your own branch name forward to include all the new commits introduced by this.  And of course, `git pull` just means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command, usually `git merge`*.

The complications matter, but the actual merging, if any, always takes place in *our own* repository.<sup>6</sup>  We also `git fetch` anyone else's commits as needed.  We end up holding all the commits locally, and can visualize our Git's commits—even if it got them from some other Git—as just existing in our repository.

> A typical feature development cycle includes daily commits and pushes on a feature branch. It also includes once daily git pulls from master to stay in sync with other changes. Sometimes this involves resolving merge conflicts.

So what we end up with here is a graph that looks like this, after several days of work:

```
...--H--K--L--N--O--R   <-- master
      \     \     \
       I--J--M--P--Q--S   <-- feature
```

where `M` and `Q` are real merge commits, some of which might involve resolving merge conflicts.

If we believe `feature` is ready *now*, we can:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

which will produce this:

```
...--H--K--L--N--O--R---T   <-- master
      \     \     \    /
       I--J--M--P--Q--S   <-- feature
```

The two parents of `T` are `R` (first parent) and `S` (second).  We *can* now delete the name `feature` entirely:

```
...--H--K--L--N--O--R---T   <-- master
      \     \     \    /
       I--J--M--P--Q--S
```

Commit `S` remains reachable by walking back through `T` to its second parent.  The merge itself is done by comparing the merge base snapshot in commit `O` to the snapshots in commits `R` and `S` and merging those.

Or, we can `git merge --squash`, after which we really *should* delete `feature` entirely.  The result *before* deleting `feature` looks like this:

```
...--H--K--L--N--O--R--T   <-- master
      \     \     \
       I--J--M--P--Q--S   <-- feature
```

The *contents* of commit `T` were made the same way in both cases; it's just that `T` has no second parent this time (so it is by definition not a *merge commit*).

Assuming we don't try to remember commits by hash ID and just forget about all the unreachable ones, the result when we delete the name `feature` looks like this:

```
...--H--K--L--N--O--R--T   <-- master
```

---

<sup>6</sup>With the clicky web UI buttons, the merge takes place in *their* Git repository, after which we must `git fetch` their merge and then update our own branch names to incorporate the new merge commit.  In general, hosting services do not allow merges that have conflicts, as the hosting services don't provide a way to resolve the conflicts.  Some hosting services might add such features over time, but I'd prefer to do conflicted merges locally, myself: you have a lot more data available easily this way.

---

#### Conclusion

Your question asked about *safety*, but without a definition of *safe* it's not really answerable.  What we can say is that the work we did in individual commits `I`, `J`, `P`, and `S` is no longer find-able.  Instead, when we look at the snapshots that remain findable, it looks as if someone wrote all the `feature` code/changes overnight.

This has good and bad aspects.  For some features, the good will outweigh the bad: there's no distractive second-parent of merge commit `T` to walk through to see individual commits like `I`, `J`, `P`, and `S`, and no need to worry about any of the merge commits in that path.  But what if there's a bug in the all-in-one changes in `T`?  *Maybe* that bug is easy to find in, say, commit `J` or commit `P`, and hard to find in `T`.  So maybe it would have been better to *retain* the individual commits.

**If you're sure you never want the original commits back, squashing is the way to go.  If you're not sure, it may not be.**

There is a compromise position, which in some ways may be the best one of all.  Instead of squash-merging, you can *rebase* the `dev` branch onto `feature`.  What rebase does is to *copy* commits.  Rebasing has its own drawbacks, though.

Here is what we have before merging:

```
...--H--K--L--N--O--R   <-- master
      \     \     \
       I--J--M--P--Q--S   <-- feature
```

There are six commits reachable from the name `feature` that are not reachable from the name `master`: `I`, `J`, `M`, `P`, `Q`, and `S`.

Doing `git checkout feature; git rebase master` will direct Git to find those six commits, *throw out any merge commits from the list*—leaving `I-J-P-S`—and then *copy* those commits, one at a time, so that the new copies come after commit `R`.  Each copy is done as if by `git cherry-pick`.<sup>7</sup>  Unfortunately, *each cherry-pick can have conflicts* and if so, you must resolve them.  They tend to be the same conflicts that you might have resolved at the now-omitted merges, and will tend to need the same resolution.<sup>8</sup>  After the copying, Git moves the branch name, so that the end result looks like this:

```
                      I'-J'-P'-S'  <-- feature
                     /
...--H--K--L--N--O--R   <-- master
      \     \     \
       I--J--M--P--Q--S   [abandoned, but the name ORIG_HEAD works to find S]
```

The names `I'`, `J'`, and so on are meant to imply that even though the new commit has a new and different hash ID, it's a *copy* of the original commit.

You can compare the snapshot in the copy `S'` to the snapshot in `S` using:

```
git diff ORIG_HEAD HEAD
```

If they do not match, you probably made a mistake while re-resolving conflicts.<sup>9</sup>

Now that you have everything neatly rebased, you can do either a fast-forward merge:

```
                      I'-J'-P'-S'  <-- feature, master
                     /
...--H--K--L--N--O--R
```

or a true merge:

```
                      I'-J'-P'-S'  <-- feature
                     /          \
...--H--K--L--N--O--R------------T   <-- master
```

and then in either case delete the name `feature` whenever it should be deleted.

The big drawback to rebasing is that *everyone* who was working with `feature` must switch to using the new rebased-`feature` commit copies.  If the feature is ready, and will have its name deleted, that's usually pretty easy.  But it definitely falls into the other rule I like to use about Git:  **Only replace commits with new-and-improved copies if everyone who is using those commits has agreed to move to the new-and-improved copies.**  This agreement should usually be made in advance.

---

<sup>7</sup>Rebase has a bewildering set of options, including `-i`, `-k`, `-m`, and `-s`, and some of these options cause it to actually use `git cherry-pick`.  Other methods use `git format-patch` and `git am` internally, but are intended to produce the same result.

<sup>8</sup>There is another Git feature and command, `git rerere` with an enable option, that allows Git to do this for you, but always remember that Git is not *smart*, it's just applying simple text substitution rules.  How `rerere` works and what can go wrong is rather tricky and I won't go into details here.

<sup>9</sup>Note that if `ORIG_HEAD` gets written by some subsequent operation, you can also use `feature@{1}` to find `S`.  If you're getting into a complicated situation where you need to know the hash ID for `S`, either copy-paste it somewhere, or create a temporary branch or tag name to hold it.

In practice, when I'm rebasing a complicated feature, what I like to do is:

```
git checkout feature
git branch feature.0    # or .1, .2, etc if I already have .0, etc
git rebase master
```

Now I have the name `feature.0` to remember the original branch tip commit.

Answer (score 2):

When Git performs a three-way merge (which is the default style of merge), it considers three points: the merge base (usually, the common ancestor) and the two heads.  It doesn't consider any of the commits in between in any way.

So if the state of the files (the root tree) in each of those commits is the same regardless of whether you're squash merging or not squash merging, then the results will be the same either way, and merge conflicts will be no better or worse.

Now, whether it is as easy to look through the history and find the intended behavior when a merge conflict *does* occur is a different story; since all you have is giant squashed commits on each side, figuring out the right resolution may be more difficult.  But the conflicts themselves shouldn't be any different.

Answer (score 1):

No reason to be afraid... lots of people do IT with `git rebase -i`. I personally follow an alternative path that won't leave stuff behind and that doesn't involve rebasing:

```
git checkout my-feature-branch
git pull # merge changes from upstream, do _not_ rebase.
# correct conflicts if they show up and finish merge
# after merge is finished/committed the only differences between your branch and upstream are related to _your_ feature and so....
git reset --soft the-upstream-branch # set branch pointer to upstream branch, all differences are set on index ready to be committed
git commit -m "the feature in a single revision"
```